# What is meant by "loose the loins of kings"?

Tags: isaiah

What is meant by "loose the loins of kings" in Isaiah 45:1?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly polite, and I do apologize if it is deemed offensive, but Bible teacher Chuck Missler addresses this phrase this way:

> In Isaiah 44 and 45, God not only describes the ease with which Cyrus would enter the city with the "two leaved gates" (gates that were not even shut against the invaders!) but also notes that He would "loose the loins of kings" before Cyrus – a euphemism regarding the fear these kings would feel and the mess in their pants they'd make as a result.
>   -- [Isaiah and Cyrus the Great](https://www.khouse.org/enews_article/2012/1934) (Koinonia House)

It seems, then, that the loosing or weakening of loins may refer to a physiological phenomenon which accompanies extreme (and in Belshazzar's case, warranted) fear.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions. I have edited your answer to format the quote so it stands out from you own words, and fixed the link that ended up displaying a print dialog.

Comment: There is a parallel passage that includes some other details such as being "bowed down" and experiencing something akin to "labor pains" that might lend credence to your idea (which was what I thought when I read it but for which I haven't found scholarly support):  Isa 21:3  Therefore are my loins filled with pain: pangs have taken hold upon me, as the pangs of a woman that travaileth: I was bowed down at the hearing of it; I was dismayed at the seeing of it.

Comment: An even less "polite" image is found in the image of uncontrolled passing of gasses akin to a harp!:  Isa 16:11  "Wherefore my bowels shall sound like an harp for Moab, and mine inward parts for Kirharesh."   My new favorite verse!

Comment: Ruminator, I have never read these verses with this appreciation. ;) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics!

The term "loins" (in Hebrew, מתן) throughout the Bible often refers to some sort of strength when the loins were girded (see [2 Kings 4:29](http://biblehub.com/2_kings/4-29.htm), for example), so loosening their loins would mean to weaken them.  This could be interpreted completely in the figurative sense (simply making them weak, or removing them from power, how most translations render it), or it may be taken a bit more literally, and be understood as disarming these kings, or removing their weapons, as many of the [translations here](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/45-1.htm) understand (see NIV, CSB, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

(Isaiah 45:1) literally has YHWH saying "... & the loins (hips) of kings I will OPEN [untie, ungird, remove, loosen] (ַאֲַפתֵּח) ..." - King CORESH (Cyrus), his servants & maybe others will untie or remove the defeated kings' belt, armor and clothing (Isa. 5:27; 1 Ki. 20:11). Sometimes the clothing that is removed is "sackcloth" (Isa. 20:2). So the word "loins" is important to signify all that because the same verb root can be used to "open (untie) sandals (also Isa. 20:2)," "opening the bond(s) or chains" (Job 12:18; 39:5 Ps. 116:16; Isa. 52:2; 58:6), "ungirding [unbinding] camels" (Gen.24:32), "opening (untying) sacks" (Gen. 42:27; 43:21; 44:11), etc.